# MS Access Form in Datasheet view Crosstab query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access form that allows the user to pull projected data and historical data from multiple sources.  The historical data is summarized using a crosstab query, qryHistoricalOverview, to manage the variable number of dates that can be selected.  I then use a select query, qryODLaneSummary, to join the historical and projected data together.  How do I use this query as the record source to display all of the historical fields in the datasheet view?

My current code which I tried to modify from another solution does not return anything.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryODLaneSummary", dbOpenDynaset)
i = 0
While i < rs.Fields.count - 1
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Another option I have seen involves adding controls, but I worry about processing time to delete and then add all of the controls.

I have posted some sample data below. The Dated columns are the variable amount. I let the user pick the dates they want to see. I could limit the number of dates but would like to offer the flexibility if possible.

```
Orig  Dest  Plan Plan Pos 12/10/2019 12/11/2019 12/12/2019 12/13/2019  
8711L 7649N 0.38   0.38      0.2        0.2        0.1        0.3   
8719T 7649N 0.38   0.38      0.25       0.25       0.3        0.3
```

Comment: Building a stable report based on dynamic crosstab query is tricky but can be done. Review http://www.access.hookom.net/DynamicMthlyCrosstabRpt.htm. Where is your code located? Provide sample data and SQL statements.

Comment: Edit question to show data as a text table as well as SQL statements.

Comment: Access Cross-Tab queries bug out if the underlying record source has a subquery or stacks several queries.  The error messages vary and are unhelpful.  The fix is to replace record source of the Cross-Tab query with a table.  In the designer switch from the Select Tab to the Make Table tab and use the resulting Table as the Record Source for the Cross-Tab Query.  Please upvote this comment if it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply.  Mazoula I am still working through the downline effects of the make table.

Comment: @mazoula Making the table was the only way I could find to solve the issue but now I can't seem to mark the question answered.

Comment: I'll post my comment as the answer, otherwise all we have is upvoting comments.  I didn't post my comment as the answer because I had no way to test it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Cross-Tab queries bug out if the underlying record source has a subquery or stacks several queries. The error messages vary and are unhelpful.

The fix is to replace record source of the Cross-Tab query with a table. In the designer switch from the Select Tab to the Make Table tab and use the resulting Table as the Record Source for the Cross-Tab Query.